# in SASS, post selector ampersand doesnt work when used in a nested structure

Tags: css, sass

my markup is let's say:

```
<div class="container marker">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my scss would be

```sass
.container {
  .parent {
    .child {
      .marker & {
        background: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As long as I put the child styling nested in parent's with the marker class, the ampersand (&) rule doesn't engage.
but if i write:

```sass
.parent {
  .child {
    .marker & {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

everything seems fine. why? what am I missing?

example in CodePen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgRvOV

Comment: What should be the result? Can you paste the final CSS you want to have? What do you mean the ampersand should do there?

Comment: @panther , well i want the child element to have the background color when one of its parents has the marker class.Also i would prefer if i could place its styling nested so i'm sure that another .child elements lets say in container2 class wont have those styles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the output of your sass would be:

```
.marker .container .parent .child {
  background: red;
}
```

Because you are telling the sass to output `.marker &` which is saying this is the parent of this chain, so `.container` is being treat as the first child of `.marker`.

You need to do:

```
.parent {
  .child {
    .container.marker & {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Which will output the vanilla CSS:

```
.container.marker .parent .child {
  background: red;
}
```

A great tool to help you understand how you sass outputs is http://sassmeister.com/

Comment: ok. that makes sense. i wasn't sure where later i will put the marker class so i hoped that that doesn't matter. but as you said, the css interpretation is sensitive to that.

Answer (score 6):

Other alternative is by using variable(s) and [SASS’s Interpolation Syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_), using this will keep your original nesting

```
.container {
  $c: &;    // store parent into variable
  .parent {
    .child {      
      #{$c}.marker & {
        background: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```css
.container.marker .container .parent .child {
  background: red;
}
```